# Showing that the integrating factor of the equation is $\mu=\frac{1}{xy^3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As the title suggests, i need help to show that the integrating factor of the equation $$2x^{2}y^{3}+x(1+y^{2})\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$ is $\mu=\dfrac{1}{xy^3}$.
I have learnt 2 formulas in class to find such a $\mu$.

My solution is as follows:

Let $M(x,y)=2x^{2}y^{3}$ and $N(x,y)=x(1+y^{2})$.

We have $M_{y}(x,y)=6x^{2}y^{2}$ and $N_{x}(x,y)=1+y^{2}$.

We can either use $(a) \dfrac{d\mu}{dx}= \dfrac{N_{x}-M_{y}}{M}\mu$ or $(b) \dfrac{d\mu}{dy}= \dfrac{M_{y}-N_{x}}{N}\mu$.

Both expressions seem complicated and i can't seem to manipulate to obtain the required integrating factor. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: none of the two formulas is useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply $\mu=\dfrac{1}{xy^3}$ on both sides of equation then
$$\dfrac{1}{xy^3}\left(2x^{2}y^{3}+x(1+y^{2})\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=0$$
$$2xdx+\dfrac{1+y^2}{y^3}dy=0$$
which is exact
$$d\left(x^2+\dfrac{-1}{2y^2}+\ln y\right)=0$$

Comment: Thank you for your solution. However, is it possible to find the integrating factor  explicitly for this question?

Comment: It's hard to find such integrating factor for this equation, but the equation is simply separable and doesn't need that technique!

Comment: Thank you! Have a great day

Comment: You're welcome and good luck ;)